# Redirect to a section of a web page using spring

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I would like to know if it is possible to redirect from a web page to another web page (to a specific section within it, with a tag), but that the call to this second web page would go through spring boot and be returned with Spring MVC and a thymeleaf template.
In other words, if it is possible to tell spring to return a web page (I know how to do it) and redirect you to a specific section within it.

What I want to make is an application that sends you notifications of certain events, such as receiving a message in a chat, that you have been sent a request, you have been invited to an event in the calendar.... And I want the notifications to contain a link to the section of the mainhub related to that notification.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a really simple thing people tend to think would be hard in HTML:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; URL=PUT LINK HERE" /><! –– content is how long in seconds it will redirect ––>
```

Or you could use javascript:

```
setTimeout(redirect("url"),1000);function redirect(linkhere){window.location.href = linkhere;}
```